# TCL global variable inside AWK exec command

Tags: awk, tcl, tk-toolkit

I'd like to execute the following awk script (which is working well) in tcl:

```
exec awk {$1=="text" {print $0}} temp1.txt > temp2.txt}
```

BUT the problem is that "text" is comming from TK entry widget and I have to put it in a variable ($var) which is not recognized by awk:

```
set var [.entry get]
exec awk {$1==$var {print $0}} temp1.txt > temp2.txt}
```

Any idea how to skip it or make it running?

PS I'd like to stay with awk, not to change the code on tcl if it's possible.

Regards,
lucas

Comment: I haven't worked with AWK for some twenty years: don't you need quotes around the second operand of the == expression?

Comment: Also, the braces are unbalanced in your example: did you mean `exec awk {$1==$var {print $0}} temp1.txt > temp2.txt`?

Comment: Oh! Didn't notice your first example.  Seems the quotes _are_ necessary after all.  See my answer below.

Comment: Yes Hoodiecrow, you are right, the end brace is not needed. It's just copy/paste mistake. Concerning the quotes, I think tcl won't recognize them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `-v` switch in awk to pass external variable to awk:

```
exec awk -v var=$var {$1==var {print $0}} temp1.txt > temp2.txt}
```

Comment: That's elegant, and will work well with any non-binary, non-secret value. (Sucks for passwords/secret keys, but that's pretty usually the case anyway, and binary data is best processed with other tools…)

Comment: True, awk won't be able to do any strig comparisons for binary data in any case.